# AngularJS - how can i call a function in a controller with $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, scope

I am trying to call a function inside my html button to convert an array into a string. I just can't seem to call my function with this code.

html:

```
<button ng-click="arrayToString" ng-show="pl.ap>0">add to cart</button>
```

app.js:

```
$scope.arrayToString = function(){
    for (i = 0; i < addedArray.length; i++){
        addedArrayString = addedArrayString + addedArray[i];
    };
};
```

On console it's throwing an error: `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"`

Answer (score 1):

typo in code .rename `fuction` to `function`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have typo in the `function` keyword.

Also you have to **call** this function:

```
ng-click="arrayToString()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this,

```
  $scope.arrayToString = function(){
    for (i = 0; i < addedArray.length; i++){
        addedArrayString = addedArrayString + addedArray[i];
    }
 };
```